# jQuery autocomplete using Postgresql 9.2 Json

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, postgresql-9.2

I want to use a Postgresql (9.2) query returning an Json-Array to populate an Jquery autocomplete field using label and value.

My sql query returns an array that looks like:

```
[{value:"ki_ln_biganoir",label:"LN Bigarreau noir"},{value:"ki_ln_bigonnoir",
label:"LN Bigon noir"}, ... }]
```

When I store this string in an text-file, I can use it as datasource to populate the autocomplete script. 
I have problems to pass the result of the query to the autocomplte script.

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$query = "select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(s))) from (select art, id_sort as value, 
sorte_de as label from sorten) s;";
$result = pg_exec($db_handle, $query) or die('Abfrage fehlgeschlagen: ' . pg_last_error());
$list = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
pg_free_result($result);
?>
```

later in my script I want to pass the result of the query to javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonlist = JSON.stringify(<?php echo $list ?>);
    $( "#sortefrm" ).autocomplete({
        source: jsonlist,
        minLength: 2,
    });
</script>
```

I supposed the script could handle the $list in the same way it works with a flat json-file.

But it doesn't.

As far as I undestood, i do not need to call ab ajax request. It should work with the json returned by the Postgresql-query as well.